# Hide current country from a country selector

Tags: php, wordpress

We have multiple Wordpress sites running on the same framework/markup with the exact same functions to simplify updates. Now I want to add a country selector where all sites are added manually in a template file. BUT, I want the current country flag hidden.

Code sample:

```
<? 
    function makeItem($domain, $byline, $class, $url) {
    ?>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="<?=$url;?>" class="flag flag<?=$class;?>" title="<?=$domain;?> - <?=$byline;?>"></a>
        <div class="text">
            <a href="<?=$url;?>" class="domain" title="<?=$domain;?> - <?=$byline;?>"><?=$domain;?></a>
            <a href="<?=$url;?>" class="byline" title="<?=$domain;?> - <?=$byline;?>"><?=$byline;?></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    makeItem('Name 1','Byline 1', 'German', '#');

    makeItem('Name 2','Byline 2', 'British', '#');

    makeItem('Name 3','Byline 3', 'Finnish', '#');

    makeItem('Name 4','Byline 4', 'Polish', '#');

    ?>
```

I'm thinking of a solution based on the site title: bloginfo(name);
If the current site title is "Name 2" and "Name 2" exists in the "makeItem list", it get's removed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use an array, a loop and a continue-check.  Example:

```
$items = array(
    array(
        'name'   => 'Name 1',
        'byline' => 'Byline 2',
        'local'  => 'German',
        'other'  => '#',
    ),
    array(
        /* ... */
    ),
);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    // or whatever the criteria is
    if (bloginfo('name') == $item['name']) {
        continue;
    }
    makeItem($item['name'], $item['byline'], $item['local'], $item['other']);
}
```